# Cutoff frequencies of this amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, amplifier, filter, active-filter

The passband of this amplifier is 115Hz - 1.38kHz. How does one determine these values? Where's the lowpass filter and where's the high pass filter?

[image]

Comment: Can you calculate the cutoff frequency of a simple RC filter? Like is done here: http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/CRlowkeisan.htm If not, then get studying. Keywords to search for: Filter analysis, network analysis, circuit analysis. Why do you require an explanation of something that can be learned (online, from a course, from a book) when you just take the effort to learn it?

Comment: Here is a link to a program. http://320volt.com/en/texas-instruments-bedava-aktif-filtre-tasarim-programi/ It should be useful. In sum if you want to know how to calculate this, than analyse it in two steps, but there is a lot of stuff behind it and it's been a long time since i calculated pass band active filter.

Comment: *The passband of this amplifier is 115Hz - 1.38kHz* Uhm, no it is not. This circuit has a High pass behavior at the input due to the AC coupling cap. The only Low pass behavior depends on the actual GBW product of the opamp which can vary **a lot** so saying that the high pass frequency is 1.38 kHz is silly.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Sorry, I will do more googling, I just don't know where to start. My simulation showed a wide passband so I assumed it was a bandpass filter.

Comment: You should use a simulator to **confirm** the behavior of a circuit, not to draw any conclusions from it. Yes the circuit does **behave** as a BPF but that doesn't mean it **is** a BPF. It **is** an AC amplifier circuit. Due to **practical limitations** it has a low frequency cutoff and a high frequency cutoff, all AC amplifiers have this. A BPF would have **well defined** cutoff points, this circuit does not (OK, the low frequency one is reasonably well defined).

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thank you for the explanation, seems like I have got more reading to do.

Comment: Also you can search for some Matlab examples for active filters as they usually include the necesary math in the code. Ok from your recent coment I see the problem. Check this one to understand a little bit more about thoery behind it. It will help. https://www.electronicshub.org/active-band-pass-filter/

Comment: Did you notice that the op amp is connected with positive feedback? Considering that, it's not an amplifier: it detects edges on the input and the output swings between the supply rails. What's the context? The "passband" is more likely a range of PRIs expected in a radar system receiver.

Comment: As drawn this circuit does not have a supply to the OpAmp and even if added as others have pointed out we have positive feedback, not negative as required.

Comment: HINT: 2*pi*RC = 2pi*1 uf*1K. It is a simple single pole HPF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the typical error in the circuit diagram (opamp with positive feedback). We can try to establish the bandwidth of this amplifier. Assuming inverting amplifier.

The input capacitor together with 1KΩ resistor form a high-pass filter. 
And the corner frequency for this type of a filter is \$F_C =\frac{1}{2 \pi R \cdot C} \approx \frac{0.16}{RC} = 160H \textrm{z}\$

The upper corner frequency is determined by the opamp bandwidth and the amplifier gain. Fram LM833 datasheet we can find the Gain Bandwidth Product is \$15 \textrm{MHz}\$ typical and \$10 \textrm{MHz}\$ minimum. 
And the gain is \$A_V = -\frac{1MΩ}{1kΩ} = 1000 V/V\$

So, the upper cut-off frequency is

$$F = \frac{10 \textrm{MHz}}{(1000 +1)} = 10\textrm{KHz}$$

The output capacitor \$4.7\mu F\$ also form a high pass filter together with the load resistance.